# Spark SQL data source: how to use a type erasure hack to pass RDD[InternalRow] back as RDD[Row]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am creating a spark SQL data source to corporate internal data source, following the code of JDBC data source in spark SQL source code.

In spark 1.5, there is a comment in JDBCRelation.scala (JDBC data source code)

// Rely on a type erasure hack to pass RDD[InternalRow] back as RDD[Row]

where 
InternalRow and Row do not share a common base class.

How does this work? thanks.

Comment: BTW, for my customized data source codes, it passes the compiling in scala, but when running, I have the following exception:
   java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.SpecificMutableRow cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.Row,
How can I fix this? thanks.

Comment: First, please add links to sources  and source code. Second, what is your precise question: How it works? If you have to "fear" problems?